# Ideas why AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest: return 408 - Timeout

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking

Any ideas why an JSONRequestOperationWithRequest would return a 408 on a very quick JSON pull, and yet if you hit the same code again it returns normally?

This is happening in an app I've written where the first time you hit it, I get a 408 but then if I hit it again all is fine. I can then close the app and try it again and it works fine.

However if I wait 30 min or so and try it again, the initial call returns a 408 the first time, yet every time after that is returns fine. Thoughts?

dump of NSError (url has been masked in this paste)

```
    Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 408" UserInfo=0x11c44f70 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Your request timed out. Please retry the request. , AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey= { URL: http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.php }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.php, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 408, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey= { URL: http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.php } { status code: 408, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 514;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    } }}
```

Comment: 0
down vote
I'm getting the same issue Can you help me whats going wrong on server side.I'm not able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like it is something on the server end. A 408 is where the server is responds to it taking to long for a request. I am almost positive it isn't what you are doing on the app side as you try it again and it works... You will have to look into the server side, wish I could be more help.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue Can you help me whats going wrong on server side.I'm not able to solve it.